# Put users on a permanent ignore list with Colloquy

Tags: macos, irc, colloquy

On Colloquy, I have a few nicks set to be ignored, but whenever I open Colloquy after quitting it, the ignores are no longer in effect and I have to re-ignore the nicks. Is there any way to have a permanent ignore list so that my ignores will persist between quits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that supplying the `-p` option to the `/ignore` command does what I need by keeping a user ignored after the client quits.

Example:

```
/ignore -p NICKNAME
```